# A witch, a cat and a vampire are fighting for the survival of two worlds together with a dragon, an incubus, a human and a werewolf

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic, magical-creatures, powers

The series I am searching is about magical creatures who, in this alternate reality, came to our world a few years ago through some sort of portal. Basically every magical creature you can imagine from popular fantasy tropes is possible. The protagonists are three sisters - a witch (looking like a human), a catwoman (either fully human or fully house cat - not Anime-style) and a vampire. Throughout the series they become acquainted with a lot of other magical creatures, of which the following *pairs* were important:

- the witch had something going on with a male dragon and an incubus
- the catwoman had something going on with a male human
- the vampire had something going on with a female werewolf

They were supposed to find magical amulets or something similar which would lead to a catastrophe both for the magical and the mundane world if they ever were united at the same place. Some evil power was trying to get all the amulets to throw both worlds into chaos.

The series can't be much older than a few years. Like with a lot of series I stopped halfway through when there were no new books coming out for some time and would like to continue if I find the time again. I think there were supposed to be 9 or 12 books.

I've read the books in German and the main character from each book changed with each book between the three sisters so that for example every third book was about the witch. That's also why I think there was supposed to be a multiple of three as the final amount of books in the series.

Can you help me remember what this series is called?

Comment: Just for clarification, when you say catgirl, are we talking kawaiiesque regular looking girl with cat ears kind of thing? I only ask because that's not really a classical European character as opposed to the others.

Comment: @Broklynite I am not aware of the classical European name for such a creature. I remember her basically as a werecat if that makes it easier - either fully human or fully regular house cat. Not the mix you see in an Anime. But also not the mix you might expect when thinking about "were"-creatures.

Comment: @Broklynite Think Professor McGonagall, an animagus that has a cat as it's animagus form

Comment: That animagus helped a lot. I googled werecat :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's Otherworld series by [Yasmine Galenorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yasmine_Galenorn#The_Otherworld_Series) (wiki link).

The first book is Witchling which came out in 2006. Quote from the blurb:

> We're the D'Artigo Sisters: Half-human, half-Faerie, we're savvy--and
>   sexy--operatives for the Otherworld Intelligence Agency. But our
>   mixed-blood heritage short-circuits our talents at all the wrong
>   times.  My sister Delilah shapeshifts into a tabby cat whenever she's
>   stressed.  Menolly's a vampire who's still trying to get the hang of
>   being undead.  And me?  I'm Camille--a wicked-good witch.  Except my
>   magic is as unpredictable as the weather, which my enemies are about
>   to find out the hard way...